# non resizable web page using asp.net as

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

hi i want to create web page which can not be maximized or minimize 
how to create such,, and sometime we can see some advertising page which is fixed so i want to create like that,,

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. Your web page can't handle the state of the browser. And also you won't able to prevent the zooming of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, set the width and the height of every single element?

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript you can make your page resize itself back to its intended size, but beware for you have no control of a user's viewarea. What this means is that not every client has the ability to display 1240x720 or whatever the case may be in your one-size-fits-all methodology.

You can use something like this within your body tag:

```
<body onResize="javascript:changeBackTo(800,600)">
```

And this as a script:

```
function changeBackTo(myWidth,myHeight) {
    window.resizeTo(myWidth,myHeight);
}
```